# Unauthorized error oauth2 client from database

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I've got problem with error "Unauthorized" in my app. I'm using Spring Security and oauth2. My Clients and Users are store in database. I have got error 401 in PostMan when I start to use Client from database. Client is saving in database but still I've got error when I want to get token access from localhost:8080/oauth/token. Below is my source :

AuthorizationServerConfig :

public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;



@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;


private CustomClientDetailsService customClientDetailsService;



@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.withClientDetails(customClientDetailsService);

}


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

}

This is my CustomClientDetails :

public class CustomClientDetails implements ClientDetails {

```
final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomClientDetailsService.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6602529451366778198L;

private Clients clients;

public CustomClientDetails(final Clients clients){
    this.clients = clients;
}

@Override
public String getClientId() {
    return clients.getClientId();
}

@Override
public Set<String> getResourceIds() {
    final Set<String> resourcesIds = new HashSet<String>();
    resourcesIds.add(clients.getResourceIds());
    return resourcesIds;
}

@Override
public boolean isSecretRequired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getClientSecret() {
    return clients.getClientSecret();
}

@Override
public boolean isScoped() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Set<String> getScope() {
    final Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
    scopes.add(clients.getScope());
    return scopes;
}

@Override
public Set<String> getAuthorizedGrantTypes() {
    final Set<String> authorizedGrantTypes = new HashSet<String>();
    authorizedGrantTypes.add(clients.getAuthorizedGrantTypes());
    return authorizedGrantTypes;

}

@Override
public Set<String> getRegisteredRedirectUri() {
    final Set<String> registeredRedirectUris = new HashSet<String>();
    registeredRedirectUris.add(clients.getWebServerRedirectUri());
    return registeredRedirectUris;
}

@Override
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(clients.getAuthorities()));
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public Integer getAccessTokenValiditySeconds() {
    return clients.getAccessTokenValidity();
}

@Override
public Integer getRefreshTokenValiditySeconds() {
    return clients.getRefreshTokenValidity();
}

@Override
public boolean isAutoApprove(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalInformation() {
    final Set<String> additionalInformation = new HashSet<String>();
    additionalInformation.add(clients.getAdditionalInformation());
    return null;
}
```

This is a CustomClientDetailsService :

public class CustomClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
private ClientsRepository clientsRepository;

@Autowired
private CustomClientDetails customClientDetails;

@Override
public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {

    Clients client = clientsRepository.findByClientId(clientId);

        final CustomClientDetails customClientDetails = new CustomClientDetails(client);
        return customClientDetails;
    }
```

And error from PostMan :

{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-20T09:32:15.479+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a `client_id` and a `client_secret` in postman, in the authorization section, you can set a Basic Auth. [image]

In the `username` field, put your `client_id` and in the `password`, put your `client_secret`.

Comment: okay, have you configured the the client_id and the client_secret, because i don't see it in your code :)

Comment: The cilent_id and client_secret are store in database

Comment: client_secret probably must be in a hashed form. Is there anything useful in logs if you set the logging level to debug or even trace?

Answer (score 0):

"Unauthorized" at "/oauth/token" probably means you didn't provide `HTTP Basic Auth` credentials in request headers. As far as I recall this endpoint is secured by default with login and password stored in `oauth_client_details` entity. Look for `client_id` + `client_secret` pair and provide it to Postman with Authorization->Basic Auth settings.